# Pyspark job aborted error due to stage failure

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following piece of code:

```
# fact table
df = (spark.table(f'nn_squad7_{country}.fact_table')
     .filter(f.col('date_key').between(start_date,end_date))
     #.filter(f.col('is_lidl_plus')==1)
     .filter(f.col('source')=='tickets')
     .filter(f.col('subtype')=='trx')
     .filter(f.col('is_trx_ok') == 1)
     .join(dim_stores,'store_id','inner')
     .join(dim_customers,'customer_id','inner')
     .withColumn('week', f.expr('DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(date_key, 1), "Y-ww")'))
     .withColumn('quarter', f.expr('DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(date_key, 1), "Q")')))


#checking metrics
df2 =(df
      .groupby('is_client_plus','quarter')
      .agg(
        f.countDistinct('store_id'),
        f.sum('customer_id'),
        f.sum('ticket_id')))

display(df2)
```

When I execute the query I get the following error:

> SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 58 in stage 13.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 58.3 in stage 13.0 (TID 488, 10.32.14.43, executor 4): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'Q'

I'm not sure about why I'm getting this error because when I run the fact table chunck alone I'm not getting any kind of error.

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: don't know why that happened, but try using `quarter(DATE_SUB(date_key, 1))` instead of `DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(date_key, 1), "Q")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) of Spark 3, 'Q' is a valid datetime format pattern, despite it's not a valid Java time format. Not sure why it didn't work for you - maybe a Spark version issue. Try using the function `quarter` instead, which should give the same expected output:

```
df = (spark.table(f'nn_squad7_{country}.fact_table')
     .filter(f.col('date_key').between(start_date,end_date))
     #.filter(f.col('is_lidl_plus')==1)
     .filter(f.col('source')=='tickets')
     .filter(f.col('subtype')=='trx')
     .filter(f.col('is_trx_ok') == 1)
     .join(dim_stores,'store_id','inner')
     .join(dim_customers,'customer_id','inner')
     .withColumn('week', f.expr('DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(date_key, 1), "Y-ww")'))
     .withColumn('quarter', f.expr('quarter(DATE_SUB(date_key, 1))')))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_format) of the function, it explicitly states what pattern letters are valid to use:

```
All pattern letters of the Java class java.text.SimpleDateFormat can be used.
```

You can see the valid patterns here:

```
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
```

It looks like `Q` is not one of them.  As per the comments @mck shows a suitable alternative.